# Why doesn't this behave the way I expect (hope) it would?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have a several protocols set up in my framework to deal with resources. In one of the protocols, I have set up an extension to provide a default implementation for a `decode` function. It's simpler to show the code and what happens (see calls to `fatalError`). There's a lot more code in the actual implementation, but this illustrates the issue:

This is the "base" protocol:

```
public protocol Resourceful {
    associatedtype AssociatedResource
    typealias ResourceCompletionHandler = (AssociatedResource?, Error?) -> Void

    func fetch(_ completion: @escaping ResourceCompletionHandler)
}
```

This is a generic, concrete implementaion of Resourceful:

```
    open class WebResourceApiCall<Resource>: Resourceful {
    public typealias AssociatedResource = Resource
    public typealias FetchedResponse = (data: Data?, urlResponse: URLResponse?)

    public init() {
    }

    public func fetch(_ completion: @escaping ResourceCompletionHandler) {
        try! decode(fetched: (data: nil, urlResponse: nil))
    }

    public func decode(fetched: FetchedResponse) throws -> Resource {
        fatalError("It ends up here, but I don't want it to!")
    }
}

extension WebResourceApiCall where Resource: Decodable {
    public func decode(fetched: FetchedResponse) throws -> Resource {
        fatalError("This is where I want it to go...")
    }
}
```

This is how I'm attempting to use it:

```
public struct Something: Decodable { }

var apiCall = WebResourceApiCall<Something>()
apiCall.fetch { _, _ in } // Implictly calls decode... but not the decode I expected it to! See fatalError() calls...
```

Instead of calling `decode` on the extension, like I hoped it would, the "default" `decode` method with no constraints is always called.

Why doesn't this work the way I expect it to?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Swift is a statically dispatched language, thus the address of the `decode()` function to be called is computed at compile time, and because the call happens inside the base definition of the class, the compiler picks the original implementation.

Now, if you call the method from a place where the compiler has enough information to pick the implementation you need, it will work:

```
var apiCall = WebResourceApiCall<Something>()
try apiCall.decode(fetched: (nil, nil))
```

The above code will call the method from the specialized extension, as at this point the compiler is a better position to know that it has a more specialized implementation to call.

It should be possible to achieve the behaviour you need if you move the `decode()` method in the dynamic dispatch world - i.e. at the protocol level.